# How to add MessageGroupId parameter to message?

Tags: java, amazon-sqs, spring-jms

I am trying to send message to AwsSQS fifo queue using `JmsTemplate`.

**Code:**

```
Message message = new Message().withBody("Hi");
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(message);
```

When I run the above code I'm getting the error

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.AmazonSQSException: The request must contain the parameter MessageGroupId. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MissingParameter; Request ID: 94f6257b-0f2e-5e3d-9469-7c1066d45816; Proxy: null)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1819) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.24.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1403) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.24.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1372) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.24.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.24.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.24.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.24.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.24.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.24.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.24.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.24.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.24.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.doInvoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2271) ~[aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.12.24.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2238) ~[aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.12.24.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2227) ~[aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.12.24.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.executeSendMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1817) ~[aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.12.24.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.sendMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1786) ~[aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.12.24.jar:na]
    at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.AmazonSQSMessagingClientWrapper.sendMessage(AmazonSQSMessagingClientWrapper.java:202) ~[amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib-1.0.8.jar:na]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

I have tried adding `MessageGroupId` like this but this is also not working

```
Message message = new Message().withBody("Hi")
                .withAttributes(Map.of("MessageGroupId", "1"));
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(message);
```

Is there any other way to send message to SQS fifo queue using `JmsTemplate`?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use the AWS SDK for java instead of JMS? It seems to call the same thing anyway.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am also using activemq that's why I'm using `JmsTemplate`

Comment: FWIW, a [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) by definition is FIFO so saying "fifo queue" is redundant.

Comment: hi @deadshot, could you please help me how you solved this ? I am facing the same issue ... PFB my sample code,                                                                                                                        attributes.put("MessageGroupId", "groupID");  attributes.put("JMSXGroupID", "groupID");                                      
       Message message = new Message()
       .withBody("Hi there")
       .withAttributes(attributes);

Comment: @Jayanth try `message.setStringProperty("JMSXGroupID", "1")` it will work

Comment: @deadshot, i dont see the method setStringProperty for message. I am using com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.Message. Is this right ?

Comment: @Jayanth I have used `jms.Message` try with this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [aws documentation](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/supported-implementations.html#jms-defined-headers-reserved-properties), you need to set `JMSXGroupID` in header or property

> JMSXGroupID (required for FIFO queues, not allowed for standard queues)

Also, have a look at the [key terms](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-key-terms.html), you might also need a de-duplication id.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the Java code for mtk Solution.

```
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsync;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.SendMessageRequest;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private AmazonSQSAsync awsAsync;
    
    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;
        
    @Value("${aws.sqs.endpoint}") 
    private String endpoint;  // fifo queue https url
    
    public void method(CustomClass obj){
    awsAsync.sendMessageAsync(new SendMessageRequest(endpoint, objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj))
                                      .withMessageGroupId("aws-sqs-group"));
    }
```

Maven dependencies used :

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>${1.12.190}</version>
    </dependency>
```